# 3ds max "thread stiching" plugin for cloths or furniture

Tags: textures, 3dsmax

i`m trying to find a plugin or way to add 3D thread stiching to a mesh.

It would be perfect if you could creat thread stiches along edges in "editpoly" mode.
I know that you can somehow do this in Z-Brush with customized alpha brushes but in my opinion its a bit complicated. I could also imagine alining a editable spline along a mesh edge.
Important for me would be that this "unknown tool" would also add the displacement on the canvas and the stiches so i can use "render to texture" to give seems realistic look. Thisway you could always creat perfect stiches with realistic looking displacement like in the picture below without to much affort.

http://www.esunroof.com/contrast_stitch.jpg

http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQplgCvhur-ynthz15Qdaqpv1QRwkG4K6sjhVjDqzzxm6OaY9Bt

would be awesome if you know a way to do this, Thanks a lot lot :)

Comment: if you think this question should be on the 3D Graphics, Modeling and Applications page please commit here:[link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics-modeling-applications)

Answer (score 1):

If this is for use in a game, there is no way you'd add that as mesh geometry.

This is almost an example case for the use of bump/normal/displacement maps.

These would allow you to keep the geometry of a model simple, but the texture maps you apply to it would add the seams and stitches.

In that case, photoshop (or GIMP if you're cheap) is your friend, along with [NVidia Texture Tools](http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/) which allow you to create a normal map from a texture. So, you could get an image of a real stitch, and generate a normal map from it.

Comment: Yes thats the way i do it now but seems on unwrap uvws are always a bit tricky and timeconsuming. If i had such a tool i could then render to texture and apply this tex to the lowpoly model. Thisway i could get round the distortion issue and the sticking would look better on the texture :o. Since i already use ps to do seems is your anwer not the one i was looking for. But thanks anyways...

Comment: Okay, so you're looking to bake detail on. I know there's a built in tool in Maya and Max that lets you create a piece of geometry and clone it along a spline. Can't remember the name of it though, but that would be the ideal tool to use (create a stitch pattern, run a spline along the edge of the seam, done).

Comment: Thats it ! i found a plugin called EdgeMap www.ghosttrails.net/index.php/other-plugins.html  i`m not 100% sure if it works, i can test it in approx. 8 hours. If you find the build tool you are talking about i would be happy to test it too:)

Comment: i also thought about path deform a spring along a spline but needs testing i will keep updating...